# After getting the stream_url for facebook live in android app, how to make the video live on facebook from another app?

Tags: android, facebook-live-api

I got the response from the facebook which is id, stream_url, secure_stream_url,What to do next i'm not able to get any idea, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like `ffmpeg`, Nginx RTMP module, or an app like OBS that can forward a stream to the `secure_stream_url` provided by the response from FB.